# How firebase charges for storage BANDWITH?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

Recently my firebase spark plan was disabled & I wanted to know how firebase charges for bandwith.
I see the limit is 1 GB per day but I don't know exactly how much they will be charging me after the limit. I tried searching on [Firebase Blaze Plan Calculator](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/?authuser=0&hl=en#blaze-calculator) but I couldn't found any specific section for just bandwidth charges.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's a <kbd>GB transferred</kbd> slider in that pricing calculator, which is the charge for bandwidth used for downloads.

[image]

Firebase does not have its own pricing though, and this is really just a simplified view of Google Cloud Storage network pricing, so I recommend reading up on the [Network](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#network-pricing) cost in the pricing page of that.